# series object not callable with linear regression in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, statsmodels

I am new to Python and I am trying to build a simple linear regression model. I am able to build the model and see the results, but when I try to look at the parameters I get an error and I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Code:

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
lm = LinearRegression()
lm = smf.ols(formula='medv ~ lstat', data=data).fit()
lm.describe
```

produces results

```
Dep. Variable:  medv    R-squared:  0.544
Model:  OLS Adj. R-squared: 0.543
Method: Least Squares   F-statistic:    601.6
Date:   Wed, 06 May 2015    Prob (F-statistic): 5.08e-88
Time:   15:01:03    Log-Likelihood: -1641.5
No. Observations:   506 AIC:    3287.
Df Residuals:   504 BIC:    3295.
Df Model:   1
```

But when I try to call the parameters

```
lm.params()
```

I receive this

```
Series object is not callable
```

I must be missing something but I am not sure what it is. The model is being produced correctly.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
lm.params
```

instead of

```
lm.params()
```

The latter tries to call the params as a function (which it isn't)